# Augmented Matrix Free Variables

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

My professor stated that if an augmented matrix is in the row echelon form and the bottom most row(s) is all $0$s, then there are infinitely many solutions.

However, after reading a bit more, I am starting to think that his statement is false. Isn't there only infinitely many solutions when there are free variables present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right.

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_ 2 \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}  0 \\ 0  \\ 0   \end{bmatrix}$$

has exactly one solution.

Some conditions are needed to make his statement true, first we need the system to be consistent. Also, for a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, we need $m \le n$. In fact, if $n > m$ and it is consistent, then there will always be free variables. His statement is interesting when $m=n$.

Comment: What about this thread https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309724/three-unknowns-the-last-row-of-the-matrix-contains-all-zeros

is the accepted answer saying that a row of zeroes implies the presence of free variables?

Comment: That is the case of $3$ equations and $3$ unknowns. $m=n$.