# Row Echelon Form with Zero-ed Row

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Given that I have an augmented matrix in Row Echelon Form or Reduced Row Echelon form, and the bottom row(s) contain only zeroes.

Generally speaking (disregarding fringe cases if any?):

- Why do rows of only zero imply the presence of a free variable?

  ([Three unknowns, the last row of the matrix contains all zeros.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309724/three-unknowns-the-last-row-of-the-matrix-contains-all-zeros))
- Can you have a free variable without the bottom row(s) containing
  only zeroes?
- Does the presence of a free variable always mean you have an infinite
  number of solutions?

Comment: They don't, just means you have a lineraly dependant vector. Yes, if you have more variables than equations. Yes, because its free, it means it can be anything, hence infinite number of soltuons

Comment: So it's incorrect to say that : if there is a row of zeroes, then there are infinitely many solutions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why do rows of only zero imply the presence of a free variable?

This is not true, consider matrices with more rows than columns like
$$\left(\begin{matrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right).$$
Free variables are implied by columns without pivot element.

> Can you have a free variable without the bottom row(s) containing only zeroes?

Yes, consider $$\left(\begin{matrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{matrix}\right).$$

> Does the presence of a free variable always mean you have an infinite number of solutions?

This depends on the size of the base field. If it is infinite (like $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{R}$) then yes. Otherwise no.

Comment: What about this thread https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309724/three-unknowns-the-last-row-of-the-matrix-contains-all-zeros is the accepted answer saying that a row of zeroes implies the presence of free variables?

Comment: I don't see an accepted answer there. But as I wrote: Free variables are implied by **columns without pivot element**. This is the correct characterization.

Comment: Sorry, i meant the top answer, but point taken ty